# How to measure current flowing in each resistor in parallel circuit on Tinkercad?

Tags: circuit-analysis, parallel, ohms-law

I have designed a parallel circuit on Tinkercad and I wish to measure the current flowing through each resistor using multimeter. However, the multimeters' arrangement are seemed to be weird because I have done my calculation manually and the total current should be 270 mA. I have searched on YouTube but they are in series and I am still unable to figure out ho
[image: Tinkercad]

The parallel circuit I have designed consists of three 500 ohm resistors and 1k ohm resistors, respectively (see below).
[image: Parallel Circuit]

[image: Simulation]
I have done a simulation too to confirm that my answers are correct. I appreciate your assistance and guidance on this.

Answer (score 2):

None of these connections make any real connection (red squares I've added): -

[image]

Therefore there is only current flowing through two resistors (the two RH resistors). Each is 30 mA so, the total is 60 mA. You measure 60 mA on all 5 series connected ammeters.

Comment: Just in case this answer wasn't clear enough, the areas Andy outlined in red are *not* connected together: the breadboard connections (not visible) run from a-b-c-d-e in each row, they do not connect c4-c5-c6-c7 etc.  Refer Adafruit's tutorial https://learn.adafruit.com/breadboards-for-beginners